# Is it a good practice to use AOP avoid null return from repository

Tags: java, spring

`Spring Data`‘s `Repository` may return `null` which is unexpected for me, so I use a AOP like this:

```
@Around("execution(* com.example.demo.repository.*.findOne(..))")
public Object aroundRepository(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    Object[] args = pjp.getArgs();
    Object ret = pjp.proceed(args);
    if (ret == null) throw new NullEntityException("null");
    return ret;
}
```

where `NullEntityException` is a custom exception will be handled here:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler({NullEntityException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ResponseBody
    ErrorMessage handleCustomException(Exception e) {
        return new ErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The controllers in my project are all `@RestController`. So is it the best way to prevent null return from all `findOne` method with no `if (entity == null) throw new NullEntityException("null")`boilerplates in my DAO layer ?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is the right approach/way. Using aspect for wrapping exception into custom exception is normal practice.

Also if you have custom repository implementation you can override method `findOne()` and throw from one NullEntityException or you can wrap null into some Optional or Null, instead of working with an exception, object but you need to adjust client side to handle this value.

Just remark -  `NullEntityException("null")` - a bit strange name and value , NotFoundException/ObjectNotFoundException  (EntityNotFounException is exception from java persistance , better don't create custom exception with same name) is more logically than NullEntityException.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and naming advice!

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it works fine.  But you might lose useful business information by handling these `nulls` so generically.

`null` back from a repository usually means "the item wasn't found".
Not an internal error, just that they asked for something that didn't exist.
**I would want to return a 404 response for those**.

Sometimes it might mean "something went wrong - I didn't expect a null here". 
**I would want to return a 500 for those**.

That knowledge of what `null` means is specific business knowledge in your application.  So, depending on your system, your repository might not in a position to apply a generic solution like this.

But if you're sure that `null` ALWAYS means something went horribly wrong, and you ALWAYS want to throw a 500 back for that, then what you've got is fine.